# Magento 2 I have added the custom field in the product attributes field but that not get save value at edit time in product attributes form

Tags: magento2, database, product-attribute, image, custom-field

I have add the custom text field at the **stores->attributes>product**  in form  field that save into database but when i return edit that attributes that value not set at the edit times.

Here is the Image of the my custom field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should reindex of product attribute and then flush Magento cache.